# Download a compressed zip file from URL

Tags: python, python-3.x, web

I have a problem statement where I have to login to a website and then download a zip file. I have written the below code so far to login to website(able to print authentication successful message) and create a session. How can I download the zip file now ?

```
import requests
import urllib
import urllib.request
import zipfile
import io
import shutil

post_login_url = 'https://www.ims-dm.com/mvc/page/customer-sign-in/cgi/cookie.php' 
request_url = 'http://www.ims-dm.com/cgi/securedownload.php?p=WPNFTPD#prodtype=wpn/WPN-FULL-20180306.TXT.zip'

payload = { 
         'sendusername':'xxxxxxxxxx', 
         'password':'xxxxxx'
} 

with requests.Session() as session:
    post = session.post(post_login_url,data=payload)    
    if post.status_code == 200:
        print("Authentication sucessful !!")
        url = session.get(request_url)
```

Comment: session.get(the_zip_url)

Comment: And then just unzip the response data: https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html

Comment: I have added the below lines of code.
  url = session.get(request_url)
  zipfile.ZipFile.extractall(url)
I am getting the bellow error.

Authentication sucessful !!
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\x0cw\Downloads\login.py", line 21, in <module>
    zipfile.ZipFile.extractall(url)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python\Python36\lib\zipfile.py", line 1493, in extractall
    members = self.namelist()
AttributeError: 'Response' object has no attribute 'namelist'

Comment: zipfile.ZipFile(io.BytesIO(url.content)).extractall()